# Moving data from a CDateTimeCtrl to a CTime object in VC++ 6

Tags: mfc, visual-c++-6

Working with VS6 I noticed that some of my dialog boxes would crash when the date was changed in a CDateTimeCtrl object.  Investigating this revealed that the call to DDX_DateTimeCtrl was moving 12 bytes of data onto a CTime object that is 4 bytes wide.  Can anyone explain why this might be happening?  Does anyone know how to correct it?

Header:

```
#if !defined(AFX_DATEDIALOG_H__B9373304_D774_4447_A4D1_BB4E1FB3404F__INCLUDED_)
#define AFX_DATEDIALOG_H__B9373304_D774_4447_A4D1_BB4E1FB3404F__INCLUDED_

#if _MSC_VER > 1000
#pragma once
#endif // _MSC_VER > 1000
// DateDialog.h : header file
//

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CDateDialog dialog

class CDateDialog : public CDialog
{
// Construction
public:
    CDateDialog(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor

// Dialog Data
    //{{AFX_DATA(CDateDialog)
    enum { IDD = IDD_DIALOG_DATE };
    CDateTimeCtrl   m_StartDate;
    CDateTimeCtrl   m_EndDate;
    CTime   m_tmEndDate;
    CTime   m_tmStartDate;
    //}}AFX_DATA


// Overrides
    // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides
    //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CDateDialog)
    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
    //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

// Implementation
protected:

    // Generated message map functions
    //{{AFX_MSG(CDateDialog)
    afx_msg void OnButtonBack();
    afx_msg void OnDatetimechangeEndDate(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult);
    afx_msg void OnDatetimechangeStartDate(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult);
    afx_msg void OnCloseupStartDate(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult);
    afx_msg void OnCloseupEndDate(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult);
    //}}AFX_MSG
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
private:
    // the range limits for the dates; these are set to the values found
    // in m_tmStartDate and m_tmEndDate in OnInitDialog
    CTime m_tmStart;            // beginning of the range
    CTime m_tmEnd;              // end of the range
};

//{{AFX_INSERT_LOCATION}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ will insert additional declarations immediately before the previous line.

#endif // !defined(AFX_DATEDIALOG_H__B9373304_D774_4447_A4D1_BB4E1FB3404F__INCLUDED_)

Code:

// DateDialog.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CustomerSales.h"
#include "DateDialog.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CDateDialog dialog


CDateDialog::CDateDialog(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CDateDialog::IDD, pParent)
{
    //{{AFX_DATA_INIT(CDateDialog)
    m_tmEndDate = 0;
    m_tmStartDate = 0;
    //}}AFX_DATA_INIT
}


void CDateDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    //{{AFX_DATA_MAP(CDateDialog)
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_START_DATE, m_StartDate);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_END_DATE, m_EndDate);
    DDX_DateTimeCtrl(pDX, IDC_END_DATE, m_tmEndDate);
    DDX_DateTimeCtrl(pDX, IDC_START_DATE, m_tmStartDate);
    //}}AFX_DATA_MAP
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CDateDialog, CDialog)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CDateDialog)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON_BACK, OnButtonBack)
    ON_NOTIFY(DTN_DATETIMECHANGE, IDC_END_DATE, OnDatetimechangeEndDate)
    ON_NOTIFY(DTN_DATETIMECHANGE, IDC_START_DATE, OnDatetimechangeStartDate)
    ON_NOTIFY(DTN_CLOSEUP, IDC_START_DATE, OnCloseupStartDate)
    ON_NOTIFY(DTN_CLOSEUP, IDC_END_DATE, OnCloseupEndDate)
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CDateDialog message handlers

void CDateDialog::OnButtonBack() 
{
    // exit with our buton ID
    EndDialog(IDC_BUTTON_BACK);
}

void CDateDialog::OnDatetimechangeEndDate(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) 
{
    if(m_EndDate.GetMonthCalCtrl() == NULL)
    {
        UpdateData();

        if(m_tmStartDate > m_tmEndDate)
            m_tmStartDate = m_tmEndDate;

        UpdateData(FALSE);
    }

    *pResult = 0;
}

void CDateDialog::OnDatetimechangeStartDate(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) 
{
    if(m_StartDate.GetMonthCalCtrl() == NULL)
    {
        UpdateData();

        if(m_tmEndDate < m_tmStartDate)
            m_tmEndDate = m_tmStartDate;

        UpdateData(FALSE);
    }

    *pResult = 0;
}

void CDateDialog::OnCloseupStartDate(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) 
{
    UpdateData();

    if(m_tmEndDate < m_tmStartDate)
        m_tmEndDate = m_tmStartDate;

    UpdateData(FALSE);

    *pResult = 0;
}

void CDateDialog::OnCloseupEndDate(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) 
{
    UpdateData();

    if(m_tmStartDate > m_tmEndDate)
        m_tmStartDate = m_tmEndDate;

    UpdateData(FALSE);

    *pResult = 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please publish your code here including declaration in header file. So we can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I have observed the bug with the CDateTimeCtrl a long time ago. The [GetTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt32ce9h.aspx) method of the class would crash if used with the CTime variable. I remember that at that time I have found a reference in the Internet related to this problem. I cannot find it now. The proposed solution was to use COleDateTime.

It seems that the similar problem exists with the DDE/DDX exchanges, and it has not been fixed in the latest MFC.

The simplest workaround for me at that time was to use the COleDateTime variables.

The [DDX_DateTimeCtrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs2yccx1.aspx) works with CTime and COleDateTime, so the solution for you will be to use the COleDateTime for your `m_tmEndDate` and `m_tmStartDate` variables.